# 2sxc adam uploader with automatic image resize

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Is there any plan or is already implemented image resize at upload?

I know that I can use image handler to auto resize images, but it would be great if I can make automatic upload resize to some "normal" web size image and compression because people upload images directly from the camera with file size 3Mb-5Mb and this rapidly use hosting space and backup space.

It would be great If I can setup max image width and height and default compression for images. eg: maxwidth=1920, maxheight=1080, compression/quality=0.6,
and later for displaying images I still can use imagehandler

Comment: You should consider accepting the answers that solve / answer your question(s).  Just click the check mark by the answer.  This allows the person who answered to gain reputation and helps others who come across your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now it's not on the radar, since it introduces many new potential user issues which would increase support need; a bit like when the upload size limit is too small - it always causes extra support.

So as of now, we don't plan to introduce it. You could create it yourself quite easily, by creating your own library-input-type (also using dropzone-js for the upload) and in that input type, re-configure dropzone to pre-compress.